# Zero COUNTs in JOIN with three tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have three tables; County, Cemetery & Graves.  The Marked column in the Graves table is boolean.  The query result should include the number of "Marked" graves in each cemetery including the zero count.

```
    County
-------------------------
|  CountyID  | Name      |
-------------------------|
|   351      | Lee       |
|   352      | Glascock  |
-------------------------


   Cemetery
--------------------------------------
| CEMID  |  CountyID  | Name          |
--------------------------------------|
|  1     |      352   | Smith Family  |
|  2     |      352   | Adams Family  |
|  3     |      352   | Jones Family  |
|  4     |      351   | Harris Family |
--------------------------------------

   Graves
--------------------------------------
|  ID | CEMID |     Name     | Marked |
--------------------------------------|
|  1  |   1   | John Smith   |   Y    |
|  2  |   1   | Mary Smith   |   N    |
|  3  |   1   | Frank Smith  |   Y    |
|  4  |   1   | Jane Smith   |   N    |
|  5  |   2   | John Adams   |   Y    |
|  6  |   2   | Ed Adams     |   N    |
|  7  |   3   | Susan Jones  |   N    |
--------------------------------------

   Query Result
----------------------------------
|  CEMID |     Name       | Count |
----------------------------------|
|  1     |  Smith Family  |  2    |
|  2     |  Adams Family  |  1    |
|  2     |  Jones Family  |  0    |
----------------------------------|

My current SELECT statement:

SELECT Cemetery.Name, Cemetery.CEMID, COUNT(Grave.Marked) AS Count
         FROM Cemetery
         JOIN County
         ON Cemetery.CountyID = County.CountyID
         JOIN Grave
         ON Cemetery.CEMID = Grave.CEMID
         WHERE CountyID = 352
         AND Grave.Marked = TRUE
         GROUP BY Cemetery.CEMID;
```

This statement returns the result but doe not include the Jones Family cemetery because the Marked count is zero.  I understand that the "Grave.Marked = TRUE" is in the wrong place, but where should I qualify the Count to include a cemetery where the Marked count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `left join`:

```
SELECT c.Name, c.CEMID, COUNT(g.Marked) AS Count
FROM Cemetery c LEFT JOIN
     Grave g
     ON c.CEMID = g.CEMID AND g.Marked = TRUE
WHERE c.CountyID = 352
GROUP BY c.CEMID;
```

Changes to the query:

- The `county` table is not needed.  You can get the id from `cemetary`.
- The `join`s are now `left join`.
- The condition on `Marked` has been moved to the `on` clause instead of the `where` clause.
- The use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  The execution time was rather long for the query.  It took almost 33 seconds on the example from my database with 200 cemeteries and 900 graves.

Comment: If this query is taking seconds to complete on such small data, then you need indexes on columns used in the `join`.